# Adding and appending value to an array with Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a React.js app's where the user can upload a song to firebase and then he will see the queque with all the uploaded songs in order. Queque can be sorted with a drag and drop system, that will be update the database in Firebase. When uploading a songs, is there a way to insert that songs in an array? The schema will be:

```
project-name:
[0]:
   - name
   - artist
   - duration
[1]:
   - name
   - artist
   - duration
[ecc]
```

How can I add an array and then append items in the database?
I'm using nodejs for backend and socket.io to send new sorted queque to node.

uploadSongs.js:

```
queueRef.set()
queueRef.update({
   ...metas,
   path: fileName,
}, (error) => {
   if (error) {
      console.log("Data could not be saved." + error)
   } else {
      console.log("Data saved successfully.")
   }
})
```

songs.js:

```
io.on('connect', socket => {
    var quequeRef = admin.database().ref()
    quequeRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var queque = snapshot.val()
        if (queque != null) {
            var value = Object.values(queque)
            io.emit('queueSongs', Object.values(value))
        } else {
            io.emit('queueSongs', [])
        }
    })
    socket.on('queueSongs', (songs) => {
        console.log(songs)
        quequeRef.set(songs, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Data could not be saved." + error)
            } else {
                console.log("Data saved successfully.")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) instead of queque?  Can you share any code that you've written that doesn't work the way you expect?  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) has lots of examples to learn from.

Comment: Yeah, I mean queue lol sry. I want to add an array in the database with the que, that will be updated every time. But when I try to append a song to the database is seen as a map that has as name a random id generated by firebase

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have that isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. I just found that unique IDs generated by Firebase are ordered chronogically. So when song queue is changed, it will simply order new queue and send again to the realtime database

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is how I would do it.

You have an collection called `que` inside of your collection `que` you have documents.

when you add your information to your document you may want to add an key called `orderId`.

so this is how your document will look

```
{
orderId:0,
artist:'haddaway',
title:'baby dont hurt me'
}
```

So when you are fetching your data you do something like

```
db.collection('que').orderBy('orderId').get()
```

That way you will always get the order that you put them in.

Comment: Maybe I could use orderId, but when I add a new song to the database, firebase autogenerate an id with alphanumerical characters... can I access anyway?

Comment: yes, because you have the orderID that will control the order of the list. The autoId each music get does not matter at all.